# How to pass variable to DB.from in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm just starting to use [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) in Ruby, and like it alot.

I want to pass a variable to the "from" method. So instead of calling a method like so:

```
DB.from(:items)
```

I'd like to call the method with a variable. For example:

```
# both of the following approaches fail
tableName = "items"
DB.from(tableName)
DB.from(:tableName)
```

But it fails with a sql error about a value that's not in my variable. I don't think this is a Sequel issue... I think it's a "***I'm new to Ruby***" issue.

How can I pass a variable to the **from** method above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below using [`String#to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_sym) method :

```
DB.from(tableName.to_sym)
```

Looking at the documentation of [`Sequel::Database#from`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#method-i-from), it seems it accepts all arguments as symbols. Thus you need to convert the string object pointed by the local variable `tableName`, to a symbol object.

Comment: thanks! i read those docs but i didn't get that from it.... i tried the "to_sym" method and it worked great...